# How to build on top of a dead Framework in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, github, composer-php

Im a WordPress developer and I have created plugins using the [Herbert Framework](https://github.com/getherbert/herbert) . The project is currently dead and I wish to fork it and continue to build upon it. How can I go about doing this? I want to be able to change the ORM so that the user can decide between Eloquent, PDO, Doctrine etc. Should I just take it and keep adding code or just copy code and build my own from scratch?

Comment: **Fork it** then add yours to packagist or use the VCS option in composer.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Should I rename the Namespace and continue to work on it or just Keep using the old name? Or is there a way i could say 
`$var = new OldFramework\NewFramework\Class()`

Comment: Please note that questions asking for opinions or suggestions are off topic for Stack Overflow: See [Allowed Topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @FluffyKitten __a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development__ <- This falls in this category

Comment: It is "*primarily opinion-based*", which is one of the reasons provided to flag a question for deletion. (Note I haven't flagged it... there are *much* worse questions here. Just pointing it out for future reference)

Answer (score 0):

That is why forks exist in github, you can just fork the project (which would give you the code) and keep on adding whatever you want on top of it, if you want you can even [create a pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork/) so the original repo gets your modifications,

This is how the github collaborative model works in general,

I hope this helps

Comment: I'd note that while Github gives the ability to fork, one must still respect the license of the original code.

Comment: without a license, legally, the creator retains all rights from his work, however, the terms of service on github give rights to the users to fork any public repository.

Comment: @JuanSebastian It would be of no use to create a pull request since the repo is dead, have tried, didn't work. As for the License its MIT. Should I rename the Namespace and continue to work on it or just Keep using the old name?

Comment: @JuanSebastian See https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1154/how-does-githubs-forking-right-cope-with-an-all-rights-reserved-project - being able to fork it on Github isn't the same as being legally permitted to take over the project.

Comment: indeed, it is not the same, however, the terms of usage on github clearly state "If you publish your source code in a public repository on GitHub, according to the Terms of Service, other GitHub users have the right to view and fork your repository within the GitHub site." - https://help.github.com/articles/licensing-a-repository/

Comment: Yes, you can press the "fork" button to copy the repo. No additional rights are granted by this action. The original owner could technically immediately file a DMCA takedown if you've gone and forked a proprietary public repository, and if it's GPLed or MITed or something similar the license still fully applies to the forked code.